# pgAdmin query tool text highlights

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Where  is option for pgAdmin  for highlights same words in query window?

That is, I need if  selected word `asd` in query window, also checked/selected all `asd` words in this whole text.

In query tool window I not found anything for this.

pgAdmin ||| version `1.22.0 beta`

Answer (score 0):

So far, in version 1.22.2, there is no such feature. Alternatively, I use notepad ++ as the editor and then run on pgadmin.